# Texmaker - Shortcut Key Right

Tags: texmaker, tags

I use Texmaker and its fabulous user tags in the form of commands :foo→
We type a colon, the name of our tag and we validate with the right arrow. I would like to change the validation from the right arrow to another key.
Ideally another key.
I would like to know if it is possible to modify this validation key, unless I modify the behaviour of my keyboard directly.

[Sorry for my poor english]